# Interpreting triangles in RC high pass filter circuit diagram

Tags: circuit-analysis, diagram, high-pass-filter

I came across the following image of a RC high-pass filter

[image: RC high pass filter]

There is also an initial analysis that says that there is an initial condition for the output voltage that says $$v_O(0^-) = 0$$  which apparently implies that the capacitor voltage satisfies $$v_C(0^-) = 1V$$

I am not sure how this implication is derived, because I do not understand the circuit diagram, more specifically what the triangles mean. I would like to use KVL but then would need a closed loop. From wikipedia and other sources I have looked at the example image of a RC high pass filter is

[image: standard RC high pass filter]

Are these two images equivalent and what does the triangles in the upper image mean?

Comment: What triangles? Oh, you mean the 0 volt symbols!! (also used for ground).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those triangles mean "common" (often referred to as "ground", but that is a discussion for a different question).

They are all connected, and yes, your second image is equivalent to the first.

These are very common on schematics because they help simplify and improve the readability.  Most circuits will have many points connect to common, so instead of lines all over the place they just drop a downward pointing triangle like that.  You are rarely concerned with what the common (or ground) is doing and are more focused on the rest of the circuit.

You can think of them like "all currents return through the triangles".